# Git for Windowsに付属しているbashコンソールからrubyを実行すると指定した引数が書き換わる

Tags: ruby, git, bash

環境
OS：windows7 64bit
git: 1.9.5.msysgit.1 32bit
ruby: 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
※git操作等は全て問題なく動作している状態

本現状を具体的に説明しますと、git for windows に付属している git bash を起動し、
rubyのスクリプトを実行すると、指定した引数の値がrubyに引き渡った時点で
書き換わります。
たとえば、

> $ ruby -e "puts ARGV" "/home/user" "test123"

とすると、以下が表示されます

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/home/user
>   test123

本来なら

> /home/user
>   test123

となることを想定していました。

ちなみに、git bash 上で "$ ls /" とすると C:/Program Files (x86)/Gitフォルダ内のファイルが表示されます。

> $ ls /
>   Git Bash.vbs  ReleaseNotes.rtf  bin  cmd  doc  etc  lib  libexec  share  ssl  unins000.dat  unins000.exe

また、引数の先頭を"//"とすると正しく表示されます

> $ ruby -e "puts ARGV" "//home" 
>   /home

しかし、"//home/user" とすると、正しく表示させません

> $ ruby -e "puts ARGV" "//home/user" 
>   //home/user

このことから git bash では "/" が特別な意味を持っていそうですが、書き換わる理由がわかりません。
そもそも、git bash で ruby を動作させることが問題かもしれませんが、何か解決方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSYS(MinGW)の [Posix Path Conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) によるものです。MSYSのBashが外部プログラムを起動する際に、その引数にあるパス(らしきもの)を一定のルールに従って変換します。そのルールについては [リンク先](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) にありますので、それをうまく利用して望む動作にできるかもしれません。

Comment: Posix Path Conversion に記載された "\ converted to /" を利用することで希望の動作となりました。が、利用者からすると "/home/user" を "//home\user" に書き換える必要があり、利用者全員にPosix Path Conversionを周知する必要があるため、git bash を利用せず、通常のコマンドプロンプトから使用することにします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 6):

多分ですけど、お使いの git bash は MSYS の bash だと思います。

MSYS の bash は、ヒューリスティックを使って、勝手に引数の posix path を windows の path に変換する様子です。

ソース: https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Native-MinGW-File-Name-Conversion.html

---

具体的なケースは違いますけど、 make の引数が勝手に変わってしまうのをどうにかしたいという質問が本家に上がっていました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line

そこでの回答は、 MSYS make を使うな、が accepted answer だったので、今回も同様に、 MSYS bash (すなわち、議題の git bash ) を使うな、が答えになるのではないかと考えています。

具体的には、 cygwin の bash を使え、に集約するのではないか、と考えています。

というのも、 [Using Cygwin effectively with Windows](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) にあるように、cygwin  の環境下では、 windows 用のバイナリに対しては (もっというと、 cygwin の gcc でビルドされたわけではない windows 上の exe ファイルに対しては) パスの変換がかからない様子だからです。おそらく、どこでパスの変換を行うかが cygwin と MSYS では設計が違っていて、 cygwin は各実行 exe が必要に応じて、実行時ライブラリ`cygwin1.dll`によってパスを変換するのに対し、 MSYS ではシェルがそのパス変換の責務を負う設計になっている様子です。

Answer (score 1):

MinGW Gitにある、Git CMDの方、git-cmd.exeをrubyのパス設定して、起動すれば、コマンドプロンプトにて、git, rubyが使えて、想定されているような返りが得られると思います。

起動のエイリアスのTargetにて、git-cmdをrubyのパスをセットして起動する。

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\ore-setrbvars.bat
```

ore-setrbvars.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Determine where is RUBY_BIN (where this script is)
PUSHD %~dp0.
SET RUBY_BIN=%CD%
POPD

REM Add GRADLE_BIN to the PATH
SET GRADLE_BIN=C:\gradle-3.1\bin
SET PATH=%GRADLE_BIN%;%PATH%
REM Add RUBY_BIN to the PATH
REM RUBY_BIN takes higher priority to avoid other tools
REM conflict with our own (mainly the DevKit)
SET PATH=%RUBY_BIN%;%PATH%
SET RUBY_BIN=

REM Display Ruby version
ruby.exe -v
```

使用中のものでgradleのパスも入ってますが、参考になれば幸いです。  
※使用中の環境では、システムのパスにgitもrubyも入っていません。